# a three way join mysql tables and php?

Tags: php, mysql

user_table

```
 user_id | username
       1 | solomon
       2 | muna
```

message table

```
id    user_id| message
 1       1   | this is my first message
 2       1   | this is my seocnd message
 3       2   | this is muna messgae
```

relationship table

```
  leader | follower
       1 | 2
         |
```

what i want to do is a three table join to bring out muna's friend messages, currently muna is following solomon(as shown on the followers table),

so i want the display to be like this on mona homepage

```
Solomon "this is my my first message
----------------------------------
solomon "this is my second message"
```

p.s. this is just an example database, i just wanted to see how to approach the problem, and this is what i have attempted so far!

```
 select username, message, leader
    from user, message, relationship where user.user_id =notes.user_id 
and user.user_id = relationship.leader and where user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']
```

*the session id is muna which is user_id 2

Comment: In your answer you are not using any joins, but taged question with them.

Comment: You are actually using joins. Just the old fashioned implicit syntax that you shouldn't use!

Comment: i was thinking maybe dealing with two queries rather than one!!! frist get mona followers and then retirve the followers information!! :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

heres one way of doing it

```
SELECT m.message,u.username FROM relationships r, messages m,users u WHERE m.user_id = r.leader AND r.leader = u.user_id AND u.user_id = 1
```

Spaced out

```
SELECT
    m.message,u.username #here you can use m.* to retrieve all data
FROM
    relationships r,     #Here you can define what tables you want to use
    messages m,          #within your query, always remember to do table_name letter
    users u              #this will stop ambiguity within the queries 
WHERE
    m.user_id = r.leader #make sure the message user id is the same as the leader id
AND
    r.leader = u.user_id #same as above just making the messages be filtered to the user_id 
AND
    u.user_id = 1        #your overall id will be here, if this was 2 it would affect WHERE, and AND above.
```

Within application

```
$query = mysql_query('SELECT m.message,u.username FROM relationships r, messages m,users u WHERE m.user_id = r.leader AND r.leader = u.user_id AND u.user_id = ' .  intval($_SESSION['user_id']));

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo sprintf("%s: %s",$row['username'],$row['message']);
    echo "\r\n--------------------------------------------";
}
```

This is tested and works fine on the following table structure.

---

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

INSERT INTO `messages` (`id`, `user_id`, `message`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'test'),
(2, 1, 'test 2'),
(3, 2, 'test 3');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `relationships` (
  `leader` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `follower` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `relationships` (`leader`, `follower`) VALUES
(1, 2);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `username`) VALUES
(1, 'solomon'),
(2, 'muna');
```

Comment: sorry, but you know when i put the muna session id on it or id=2 brings me no results when theres meant to be three rows back!!!

Comment: Yes, the query is assuming the user ID provided will be that of the leader. I believe the second JOIN condition should be `AND r.follower = u.userid`. Then, given `muna`, you should see `solomon`'s messages.

Comment: `m.user_id = r.leader` IS acting on the leader column of the relationships, if you wish for it to act in the user ID then follow djacobson's comment

Answer (score 4):

I'm not really that sure what your question is. Does this look like an answer to it?

```
SELECT u.username,
       m.message 
FROM   user u
       JOIN message m
       ON     u.user_id =m.user_id
       JOIN relationship r
       ON     u.user_id = r.leader
WHERE  u.user_id          = $_SESSION['user_id']
```

Comment: #1052 - Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous, thanks

Comment: `WHERE  u.user_id          = $_SESSION['user_id']`  should fix that.

Comment: when i put munas id number(which is 2) it bring me no results back, when theres meant to be three!!